# Validate employeeID through Outlook using Python

Tags: python, tkinter, outlook

Hi I am looking to validate the employee ID against outlook which I receive through tkinter from user through python. for example, a11111 is entered by the user and python should validate it and confirm if that is a valid employee in the organization.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is the actual question? Have you looked at examples of validating `tkinter` entries online? What is the problem with using `if` statements to check if the first character is a letter and the rest are numbers? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can automate Outlook from python, see [Automating Outlook using Python win32com](https://github.com/Hridai/Automating_Outlook#automating-outlook-using-python-win32com) for more information.

```
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
```

The easiest way to verify the employee ID is to find a corresponding entry in the address book and get contact's properties for verification. The [NameSpace.CreateRecipient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.createrecipient) method which creates a `Recipient` object.

```
myNamespace = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("Eugene Astafiev") 
myRecipient.Resolve 

contact = myRecipient.AddressEntry.GetContact()
```

The [AddressEntry.GetContact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.addressentry.getcontact) method returns a `ContactItem` object that represents the `AddressEntry`, if the `AddressEntry` corresponds to a contact in an Outlook Contacts Address Book (CAB).

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. I tried this with a valid employee name but the contact is not retrieved.

Comment: You may try using the [GetExchangeUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.addressentry.getexchangeuser?view=outlook-pia) method if you deal with Exchange profiles.

Comment: Hi, I tried the below and it worked. Thank you for your assistance.                                                      recipient = outlook.Session.CreateRecipient(usrid)
recipient.Resolve()